# swift fast enumeration of optionals

Tags: swift, option-type, fast-enumeration

Is there are better way to do this? Something that looks nicer syntax wise?

```
let a : [Any] = [5,"a",6]
for item in a { 
  if let assumedItem = item as? Int {
     print(assumedItem) 
  } 
}
```

Something like this, but then with the correct syntax?

```
  for let item in a as? Int { print(item) }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Swift 5, you can choose one of the following Playground sample codes in order to solve your problem.

---

### #1. Using `as` [type-casting pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#grammar_type-casting-pattern)

```
let array: [Any] = [5, "a", 6]

for case let item as Int in array {
    print(item) // item is of type Int here
}

/*
 prints:
 5
 6
 */
```

---

### #2. Using [`compactMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2957701-compactmap) method

```
let array: [Any] = [5, "a", 6]

for item in array.compactMap({ $0 as? Int }) {
    print(item) // item is of type Int here
}

/*
 prints:
 5
 6
 */
```

---

### #3. Using a where clause and `is` [type-casting pattern](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#grammar_type-casting-pattern)

```
let array: [Any] = [5, "a", 6]

for item in array where item is Int {
    print(item) // item conforms to Any protocol here
}

/*
 prints:
 5
 6
 */
```

---

### #4. Using [`filter(_:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) method

```
let array: [Any] = [5, "a", 6]

for item in array.filter({ $0 is Int }) {
    print(item) // item conforms to Any protocol here
}

/*
 prints:
 5
 6
 */
```

Comment: Functional programming (as in option 2: compactMap, flatMap) can make for some nice looking code.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Swift 2:

```
let array: [Any] = [5,"a",6]

for case let item as Int in array {
    print(item)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions

```
let a = [5,"a",6]

a.filter {$0 is Int}.map {print($0)}
```

or

```
for item in a where item is Int {
    print(item)
}
```

actually there are no optionals at all in the array

Comment: If you're using Swift2: In your first example, instead of using `map` to print each `Int` (since you'll get a warning about an unused result) you could use `forEach`: `a.filter { $0 is Int }.forEach { print($0) }` :)

Comment: I'm using Swift 2: There is no warning in a playground ;)

Comment: Try in a project, I'm not getting a warning in Playgrounds either.

Comment: Word of caution: forEach doesn't allow an early exit (breaking out of the loop).

Comment: That doesn't matter in this case: all filtered items are supposed to be printed

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `flatMap` to convert the array into `[Int]`.

```
let a : [Any] = [5,"a",6]
for item in a.flatMap({ $0 as? Int }) {
    print(item)
}
```